# Legend and checkbox get repopulated with every animation function call

Tags: python-3.x, animation, matplotlib, legend

I have a graph that displays data pulled from a database. The database gets new data added to it every minute and I need the graph to update itself, for which i'm using an animation function. I also have a interval menu to choose how many points should be displayed. All of this is put in a function that i call from somewhere else in my code. I'm having several problems with my code, i'm hoping someone can help me out:

1. each time the animation function is called, the legend and the checkbox get repopulated (as in the same information gets added at the end again and again). I have tried putting the code responsible for them outside the animation function, but then they don't get populated at all.
2. I would like the X axis to display as many ticks as the chosen interval from the menu (10, 60, 1440, 43200). Right now it displays 10, but after 2-3 updates, some ticks disappear.
3. I have read that the animation function is non-blocking, but the code i have after is not accessed anymore (this code being responsible for updating data somewhere else, so it's pretty important to be accessed). Is there any way to correct this?

Here's the the whole function:

```
from ctypes import *
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons
import matplotlib.transforms as mtrans
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import AnchoredSizeLocator
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import matplotlib
import numpy
import random
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")


main_window = Tk()

intervals = ["Last 10 minutes", "Last hour", "Last day", "Last 30 days"]  # 
equivalent to 10, 60, 1440, 43200 reads

variable = StringVar()
variable.set(intervals[0])
interval_menu = OptionMenu(main_window, variable, *intervals)
interval_menu.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=EW)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25, 5))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15, bottom=0.2)
ax.set_xlabel("Time")
ax.set_ylabel("Value")
ax.grid(color='grey')
plt.gcf().canvas.set_window_title("Chart Window")
plt.xticks(rotation=20)
plt.tick_params(labelsize='small')

axes_extent = [0.02, 0.4, 0.1, 0.15]
rax = fig.add_axes(axes_extent)
axes_locator = AnchoredSizeLocator(mtrans.Bbox.from_bounds(*axes_extent), 
                1.5, 2.5, loc="center left",
                bbox_transform=fig.transFigure, borderpad=0)
rax.set_axes_locator(axes_locator)
lines = []


def update_chart(nterval):

    extracted_data = [
                  [('0002916100036704', None, 6, '128'), ('0002916100036764', '0001677500059409', 6, '128'), ('0002916100036824', '0001677500058743', 6, '128'), ('0002916100036884', '0001677500057909', 6, '128'), ('0002916100036944', '0001677500059742', 6, '128'), ('0002916100037004', None, 6, '128'), ('0002916100037064', None, 6, '128'), ('0002916100037124', None, 6, '128'), ('0002916100037184', None, 6, '128'), ('0002916100037244', '0001677500058743', 6, '128')],
                  [('0002916100036704', None, 7, '128'), ('0002916100036764', '0001677500059409', 7, '128'), ('0002916100036824', '0001677500058743', 7, '128'), ('0002916100036884', '0001677500057909', 7, '128'), ('0002916100036944', '0001677500059742', 7, '128'), ('0002916100037004', None, 7, '128'), ('0002916100037064', None, 7, '128'), ('0002916100037124', None, 7, '128'), ('0002916100037184', None, 7, '128'), ('0002916100037244', '0001677500058743', 7, '128')],
                  [('0002916100036704', None, 8, '128'), ('0002916100036764', '0001677500059409', 8, '128'), ('0002916100036824', '0001677500058743', 8, '128'), ('0002916100036884', '0001677500057909', 8, '128'), ('0002916100036944', '0001677500059742', 8, '128'), ('0002916100037004', None, 8, '128'), ('0002916100037064', None, 8, '128'), ('0002916100037124', None, 8, '128'), ('0002916100037184', None, 8, '128'), ('0002916100037244', '0001677500058743', 8, '128')],
                  [('0002916100036704', None, 9, '128'), ('0002916100036764', '0001677500059575', 9, '128'), ('0002916100036824', '0001677500059409', 9, '128'), ('0002916100036884', '0001677500059742', 9, '128'), ('0002916100036944', '0001677500058409', 9, '128'), ('0002916100037004', None, 9, '128'), ('0002916100037064', None, 9, '128'), ('0002916100037124', None, 9, '128'), ('0002916100037184', None, 9, '128'), ('0002916100037244', '0001677500059909', 9, '128')],
                  [('0002916100036704', None, 10, '128'), ('0002916100036764', '0001677500059575', 10, '128'), ('0002916100036824', '0001677500059409', 10, '128'), ('0002916100036884', '0001677500059742', 10, '128'), ('0002916100036944', '0001677500058409', 10, '128'), ('0002916100037004', None, 10, '128'), ('0002916100037064', None, 10, '128'), ('0002916100037124', None, 10, '128'), ('0002916100037184', None, 10, '128'), ('0002916100037244', '0001677500059909', 10, '128')],
                  [('0002916100036704', None, 11, '128'), ('0002916100036764', '0001677500059575', 11, '128'), ('0002916100036824', '0001677500059409', 11, '128'), ('0002916100036884', '0001677500059742', 11, '128'), ('0002916100036944', '0001677500058409', 11, '128'), ('0002916100037004', None, 11, '128'), ('0002916100037064', None, 11, '128'), ('0002916100037124', None, 11, '128'), ('0002916100037184', None, 11, '128'), ('0002916100037244', '0001677500059909', 11, '128')],
                  [('0002916100036704', None, 12, '128'), ('0002916100036764', '0001677500059575', 12, '128'), ('0002916100036824', '0001677500059409', 12, '128'), ('0002916100036884', '0001677500059742', 12, '128'), ('0002916100036944', '0001677500058409', 12, '128'), ('0002916100037004', None, 12, '128'), ('0002916100037064', None, 12, '128'), ('0002916100037124', None, 12, '128'), ('0002916100037184', None, 12, '128'), ('0002916100037244', '0001677500059909', 12, '128')],
                  [('0002916100036704', None, 13, '128'), ('0002916100036764', '0001677500060076', 13, '128'), ('0002916100036824', '0001677500060909', 13, '128'), ('0002916100036884', '0001677500060576', 13, '128'), ('0002916100036944', '0001677500060743', 13, '128'), ('0002916100037004', None, 13, '128'), ('0002916100037064', None, 13, '128'), ('0002916100037124', None, 13, '128'), ('0002916100037184', None, 13, '128'), ('0002916100037244', '0001677500060409', 13, '128')],
                  [('0002916100036704', None, 14, '128'), ('0002916100036764', '0001677500060076', 14, '128'), ('0002916100036824', '0001677500060909', 14, '128'), ('0002916100036884', '0001677500060576', 14, '128'), ('0002916100036944', '0001677500060743', 14, '128'), ('0002916100037004', None, 14, '128'), ('0002916100037064', None, 14, '128'), ('0002916100037124', None, 14, '128'), ('0002916100037184', None, 14, '128'), ('0002916100037244', '0001677500060409', 14, '128')],
                  [('0002916100036704', None, 15, '128'), ('0002916100036764', '0001677500060076', 15, '128'), ('0002916100036824', '0001677500060909', 15, '128'), ('0002916100036884', '0001677500060576', 15, '128'), ('0002916100036944', '0001677500060743', 15, '128'), ('0002916100037004', None, 15, '128'), ('0002916100037064', None, 15, '128'), ('0002916100037124', None, 15, '128'), ('0002916100037184', None, 15, '128'), ('0002916100037244', '0001677500060409', 15, '128')]]
    number_of_attributes = 10
    number_of_intervals = 10

    x = [[None for i in range(number_of_intervals)] for j in range(number_of_attributes)]
    y = numpy.zeros(shape=(number_of_attributes, number_of_intervals))

    # ----- extract TC axis values -----
    for row_number in range(len(extracted_data)):
        for column_number in range(len(extracted_data[row_number])):
            tuple_item = extracted_data[row_number][column_number]
            y[row_number][column_number] = numeric_value(tuple_item[1])
            x[row_number][column_number] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date_value(tuple_item[0]))

    # ----- create chart lines -----
    for i in range(len(extracted_data)):
        if extracted_data[i][0][2] != 5:
            line, = ax.plot(numpy.array(x[i]), numpy.array(y[i]), visible=True, lw=2, color=get_random_color(),
                        label='Attr' + str(extracted_data[i][0][2]))
            lines.append(line)

    plt.locator_params(axis="x", nbins=number_of_intervals)
    labels = [str(line.get_label()) for line in lines]
    visibility = [line.get_visible() for line in lines]
    check = CheckButtons(rax, labels, visibility)

    def check_func(label):
        for index_label in range(len(labels)):
            if label == labels[index_label]:
                lines[index_label].set_visible(not         lines[index_label].get_visible())
        plt.draw()

    check.on_clicked(check_func)
    ax.legend(labels=labels, fontsize='x-small')
    plt.draw()


def get_random_color():
    color_list = []
    for i in range(3):
        color_list.append(float("%.1f" % random.random()))
    return color_list


def numeric_value(hex_value_string):
    if hex_value_string == None:
        return None
    first_hex = int(hex_value_string[0:8])
    second_hex = int(hex_value_string[8:16])
    i = first_hex*65536 + second_hex
    cp = pointer(c_int(i))  # make this into a c integer
    fp = cast(cp, POINTER(c_float))  
    new_float = "%.2f" % fp.contents.value
    return new_float    


def date_value(hex_value_string):
    first_hex = int(hex_value_string[0:8])      # date
    second_hex = int(hex_value_string[8:16])    # time
    i = first_hex * 65536 + second_hex - 378691200  
    return i


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_chart, interval=5000)
plt.show()
main_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve], i.e. a runnable code. Make sure to ask one question per question. See [ask].

Comment: There is no way to give all the code, it's too complex to be put here

Comment: [mcve] does by no means mean "all the code". If [mcve] is not understandable, maybe [sscce](http://sscce.org) is more understandable.

Comment: I have changed it to be runnable

Comment: I'm givin' up. But maybe someone else has the energy to explain [mcve].

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is now. If you run it the way it is, it will  produce the problems i asked about, maybe except for the 3rd one, which is more theoretical anyway